# Difference between Maven Javadoc Plugin javadoc:jar and javadoc:aggregate-jar

Tags: java, maven, jar, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

I've been using the [Maven Javadoc Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/) [`javadoc:jar`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/jar-mojo.html) goal for years, publishing many Java artifacts to Nexus (Maven Central). Currently I'm using Maven 3.8.6 with Java 17, and `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:3.4.1`.

Today I'm reading the plugin documentation (emphasis in the documentation):

- [`javadoc:jar`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/jar-mojo.html): "Bundles the Javadoc documentation for `main Java code` in an **NON aggregator project** into a jar using the standard Javadoc Tool."
- [`javadoc:aggregate-jar`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/aggregate-jar-mojo.html): "Bundles the Javadoc documentation for main `Java code` in an **aggregator** project into a jar using the standard Javadoc Tool."
- [`javadoc:aggregate-no-fork`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/aggregate-no-fork-mojo.html): "Generates documentation for the `Java code` in an **aggregator project** using the standard Javadoc Tool."

This confuses me a bit. What does the documentation mean when it refers to an "aggregator project"? Is it referring to a project using an [aggregate POM](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Aggregation), in which the parent POM lists several sub-project POMs being aggregated? Yet why would it make a difference which Maven Javadoc Plugin goal is used?

For years I have set up the Maven Javadoc Plugin in a "root POM" for all my projects. It uses the `javadoc:jar` goal. It sets up the plugin configuration for the child projects which inherit from it. Some of the child projects are standalone single-POM projects. Some of them are aggregate POMs. I've never had a problem doing it this way.

Should I be using the `javadoc:jar` goal for some projects, and the `javadoc:aggregate-jar` for other projects? But how could the root POM even know whether the child project is an aggregate project or not? What will break if I continue using the `javadoc:jar` goal for everything?

(As bonus, what is this separate `javadoc:aggregate-no-fork` goal?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, "aggregator project" refers to [project aggregation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Aggregation). Using `javadoc:jar` or `javadoc:aggregate-jar` results in different outputs:

- Running `javadoc:jar` on the parent recursively executes on all modules, as you can see in the output:

  ```txt
  [INFO] Building parent 0.0.0-SNAPSHOT                                     [1/3]
  ...
  [INFO] Not executing Javadoc as the project is not a Java classpath-capable package
  ...
  [INFO] Building module1 0.0.0-SNAPSHOT                                    [2/3]
  ...
  [INFO] Building jar: /module1/target/module1-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
  ...
  [INFO] Building module2 0.0.0-SNAPSHOT                                    [3/3]
  ...
  [INFO] Building jar: /module2/target/module2-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] Reactor Summary for parent 0.0.0-SNAPSHOT:
  [INFO] 
  [INFO] parent ............................................. SUCCESS [  0.942 s]
  [INFO] module1 ............................................ SUCCESS [  1.154 s]
  [INFO] module2 ............................................ SUCCESS [  1.126 s]
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
  ```

  Separate Javadoc outputs are created in the `target` folders of each module and bundled into separate JARs.

  Running `javadoc:jar` *only* on the parent using `--non-recursive` will not output anything.
- On the other hand, the execution of `javadoc:aggregate-jar` runs *only* on the parent:

  ```txt
  [INFO] Building parent 0.0.0-SNAPSHOT                                     [1/3]
  ...
  [INFO] >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
  [INFO] Forking module1 0.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  [INFO] >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
  ...
  [INFO] >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
  [INFO] Forking module2 0.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  [INFO] >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
  ...
  [INFO] Building jar: /target/parent-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] Reactor Summary for parent 0.0.0-SNAPSHOT:
  [INFO] 
  [INFO] parent ............................................. SUCCESS [  2.971 s]
  [INFO] module1 ............................................ SKIPPED
  [INFO] module2 ............................................ SKIPPED
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
  ```

  Javadoc is only created in one place at the parent's `/target/apidocs`, bundled into a single JAR.

  The Javadoc plugin is skipped for the modules, but the parent execution creates forked builds executing the `compile` phase for each module, to make sure all input for the Javadoc processing is present (i.e. generated sources).
- Running `javadoc:aggregate-no-fork` on the parent does not create forked builds but recursively runs on each module generating Javadocs...

  ```txt
  [INFO] Building parent 0.0.0-SNAPSHOT                                     [1/3]
  ...
  [INFO] No previous run data found, generating javadoc.
  ...
  [INFO] Building module1 0.0.0-SNAPSHOT                                    [2/3]
  ...
  [INFO] No previous run data found, generating javadoc.
  ...
  [INFO] Building module2 0.0.0-SNAPSHOT                                    [3/3]
  ...
  [INFO] No previous run data found, generating javadoc.
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] Reactor Summary for parent 0.0.0-SNAPSHOT:
  [INFO] 
  [INFO] parent ............................................. SUCCESS [  1.909 s]
  [INFO] module1 ............................................ SUCCESS [  1.082 s]
  [INFO] module2 ............................................ SUCCESS [  0.991 s]
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
  ```

  ...and also aggregates them into the parent's `/target/site/apidocs`. This command is [intended](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/javadoc-nofork.html) to be used in CI environments where all sources already have been prepared.

  In contrast to the previous commands, no JARs are created.

Comment: Oh, so it isn't so much whether the project is an aggregate, but whether the plugin creates a single aggregate JAR or multiple JARs for each project. Methinks the documentation is confusing and, dare I say, misleading. Thanks for clearing it up! I'll keep using `javadoc:jar` then, despite its admonition that it is not intended for an aggregate project, as I want individual JARs for each subproject.